# Bash error when compiling Netezza UDF

Tags: c++, bash, compilation, user-defined-functions, netezza

I have the following cpp code that defines a UDF in Netezza that takes a date of some format and changes it into the standard YYYYMMDD format:

```
//dateconvert.cpp

#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "udxinc.h"
#include "udxhelpers.h"

using namespace nz::udx_ver2;   

class Dateconvert: public Udf
{
public:

    Dateconvert(UdxInit *pInit) : Udf(pInit){}
    ~Dateconvert(){}

    static Udf* instantiate();
    virtual ReturnValue evaluate()
    {
        StringReturn* ret = stringReturnInfo();
        StringArg *str;
        str = stringArg(0);
        int lengths = str->length;
        char *datas = str->data;

        string data = datas;
        data = "'" + data + "'";
        string cmd="date -d " + data +  " +%Y%m%d 2>/dev/null";

        FILE *ls = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
        char retval[100];
        fgets(retval, sizeof(retval), ls);

        if(!isdigit(retval[0]))
        {
           strcpy(retval,"99991231");
        }
        pclose(ls);

         ret->size = sizeof(retval);
         memcpy(ret->data, retval, sizeof(retval));

        NZ_UDX_RETURN_STRING(ret);
     }
};


Udf* Dateconvert::instantiate(UdxInit *pInit)
{
      return new Dateconvert(pInit);
}
```

This is the command I use to compile/register the UDF:

```
nzudxcompile /export/home/nz/dateconvert.cpp -o dateconvert.o --sig 
"Dateconvert(VARCHAR(200))" --version 2 --return VARCHAR(200) 
--class Dateconvert --user user1 --pw password1  --db db1
```

When I go to compile, I get the error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

How can bash be generating a compilation error when compiling a c++ program? The error persists even when blanking the cpp file itself, so I would assume the issue is with the compilation command.

Comment: pass `VARCHAR(200) ` quoted...

Comment: To add to Jahid's (correct) comment, you should also be passing a literal, non-interpolated string just so that bash doesn't try interpreting `Dateconvert(VARCHAR(200))` as some function or variable.